# Is there a better, cleaner way to write this localstorage data

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, local-storage

I have some validation in my input form and I'm retaining the values through local storage. If there are any validation errors and the page reloads, I get the values from local storage and set them to their appropriate input fields. The code I have written is very long and repetitive and I was just wondering if there was a less robust way to write this code.

```
const dataArray = []

    $("#formData").on('submit', () => {
        dataArray.push($("#building").val());
        dataArray.push($("#measure_type").val());
        dataArray.push($("#status").val());
        dataArray.push($("#staff_lead").val());
        dataArray.push($("#staff_colead").val());
        dataArray.push($("#analyst").val());
        dataArray.push($("#addImpAnn").val());
        dataArray.push($("#addCategory").val());
        dataArray.push($("#addBaseCommodity").val());
        dataArray.push($("#addSource").val());
        dataArray.push($("#addPhase").val());
        dataArray.push($("#addSavingsCommodity").val());
        localStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(dataArray))
    });


    window.onload = () => {
        const getVal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('values'));
        $('#building').val(getVal[0]);
        $('#measure_type').val(getVal[1]);
        $('#status').val(getVal[2]);
        $('#staff_lead').val(getVal[3]);
        $('#staff_colead').val(getVal[4]);
        $('#analyst').val(getVal[5]);
        $('#addImpAnn').val(getVal[6]);
        $('#addCategory').val(getVal[7]);
        $('#addBaseCommodity').val(getVal[8]);
        $('#addSource').val(getVal[9]);
        $('#addPhase').val(getVal[10]);
        $('#addSavingsCommodity').val(getVal[11]);

        if(getVal[0] === null){
            $("#building").val("Choose...")
        }
        if(getVal[1] === null){
            $("#measure_type").val("Choose...")
        }
        if(getVal[2] === null){
            $("#status").val("Choose...")
        }
        if(getVal[3] === null){
            $("#staff_lead").val("Choose...")
        }
        if(getVal[4] === null){
            $("#staff_colead").val("Choose...")
        }
        if(getVal[5] === null){
            $("#analyst").val("Choose...")
        }
        if(getVal[6] === null){
            $("#addImpAnn").val("Choose...")
        }
        if(getVal[7] === null){
            $("#addCategory").val("Choose...")
        }
        if(getVal[8] === null){
            $("#addBaseCommodity").val("Choose...")
        }
        if(getVal[9] === null){
            $("#addSource").val("Choose...")
        }
        if(getVal[10] === null){
            $("#addPhase").val("Choose...")
        }
        if(getVal[11] === null){
            $("#addSavingsCommodity").val("Choose...")
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with an object and an array of the element Ids that can be looped over to both set values in the object and set values in the DOM

Something like:

```
const ids = ['building', 'measure_type', 'status'...];

let dataObj = {};

$("#formData").on('submit', () => {
  ids.forEach(id => obj[id] = $('#' + id).val());
  localStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(dataObj))
});


window.onload = () => {
   const storedVals = localStorage.getItem('values');
   if(storedVals){
      dataObj = JSON.parse(storedVals)
      ids.forEach(id => $('#' + id).val(dataObj[id] || 'Default value'));          
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save values to localStorage as record ( `{ "#building": "x", "#measure_type": "y" }` )

and then retrieve as follows:

```
Object.entries(localStorage.getItem('values')).forEach(([key, value]) => { 
    $(key).val(value ?? "Choose...") 
})
```

Comment: perhaps edit and update the answer to improve it rather than comment